# PUT vs POST in Asp.Net Web API?

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api, put

What is the difference between PUT and POST methods in Web API?
I know that POST is used to "create a new resource" and PUT is used to "update an existing resource".

But we can use POST to "update" and PUT to "Create".
So what exactly is the difference between PUT and POST?

Comment: NEVER USE ANY  GET, PUT POST .... etc methods explicitely in your APIs.  This way you will save a lot  of time on debugging error. Let a client select a metod to use your APIs.

Answer (score 0):

There is generally an expectation of behaviour and convention that your clients and co-workers will thank you for following.

At the end of the day, you can do whatever you like in your code and there's nothing that can stop you doing POST-like operations in a PUT or even DELETE-like operations in a GET.  But please don't!

Comment: I've been asked this question in interview.       If using POST we can 'update' a resource, then why is PUT used?

Comment: You can do anything you like.  You can call a variable used to store a salary "flamingo", but why would you?  You can call a SOAP web service "GetThings" and have it send emails to your local MP.  It's really just setting the expectation of what will occur.  People expect "POST" means new, PUT means modify.  It's mostly a cue, but behaviour is very much expected.  Consider it documentation if you like.